# Assigning empty quotes to a variable python

Tags: python

Why is the variable "translation" assigned to an empty string? Is that because we are going to replace it with the user's input?

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
            if letter.isupper():
                translation = translation + "G"
            else:
                translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print (translate(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

Comment: You're appending `"g"` and `"G"` to it. If you don't initialize it, what would you be appending to?

Answer (score 2):

> You're appending "g" and "G" to it. If you don't initialize it, what would you be appending to? - Aplet123

You are doing `+` to the variable. if you don't initialize it, you'll get UnboundLocalError.

And if you initialize it in the for loop, it will keep resetting the value.

That's why you are assigning at the first part of the function.

And btw, you can use `+=`

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = "" 
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
            if letter.isupper():
                translation += "G"
            else:
                translation += "g"
        else:
            translation += letter
    return translation

print (translate(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

Answer (score 2):

In line 6 you have:

```py
translation = translation + "G"
```

This tries to set `translation` to whatever string it previously was, but with `G` at the end. However, at the very start of the loop, what value is `translation`? How can we add something to it if it doesn't exist yet?

We need to initialize it so that things can be added onto it. That's what setting it to an empty string before the loop is doing.

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is assigned, it gets stored somewhere in the memory with an address. If you don't initialize(define) any location for data, how is it supposed to work?